# Django Viewflow with custom views - start different flows, depending on user selection in the first screen

Tags: django-viewflow

I have a view with `StartFlowMixin`, it contains a form  - user posts the form and a workflow starts. That works fine currently, but I need to introduce a dropdown in the form with 4 options - based on the selection in that dropdown I need to run a different flow.

E.g. the dropdown contains options like `Apply for position A`, `Apply for position B`, etc. Based on the selection the applicant needs to enter different information and different people need to approve the application.

How can I do this? One option would be to have a single workflow with a lot of ifs, but I don't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the BPMN approach for business process modeling is to record every user's decisions.

You could use flow.Switch for that case - http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_core_node.html#viewflow.nodes.Switch

Or you could use your own view, that would call required flow.StartFunction, to start actual flow - http://docs.viewflow.io/viewflow_core_node.html#viewflow.nodes.StartFunction

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. BTW I'm working on a viewflow prototype currently and if it works fine we'll buy a pro licence.